# Slow query takes .0007s? Why is this in my slowlog?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT vt.vtid, vt.tag, vt.typeid, vt.id, vt.count, tt.type, u.username, vt.date_added, tc.context, tc.contextid
FROM ( vt, tt, u )
LEFT JOIN tc ON ( vt.vtid = tc.vtid AND tc.userid = vt.userid ) 
WHERE vt.typeid = tt.typeid
AND vt.verified =0
AND vt.userid = u.userid
ORDER BY vt.date_added DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

takes .0007s to complete

```
id   select_type     table   type    possible_keys           key             key_len         ref                         rows            Extra
1   SIMPLE          vt      ref     typeid,userid,verified  verified        1               const                       9               Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          tt      eq_ref  PRIMARY                 PRIMARY         4               vt.typeid       1   
1   SIMPLE          tc      ref     vtid                    vtid            4               vt.vtid         3    
1   SIMPLE          u       eq_ref  PRIMARY                 PRIMARY         4               vt.userid       1               Using where
```

How can I change this to not show up in the slow query log?

Comment: I guess the profiler has an absurdly high standard of performance.

Comment: Just curious, what this query does?

Comment: @BoltClock the slow log threshold setting is in seconds (ie: not ms), so that shouldn't be it at all. Looks like a1ex07 figured this out, tho.

Comment: @zanlok: I know, I'd simply meant that in jest :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess. It's possible that you set `log-queries-not-using-indexes` flag. According to documentation, it may cause queries to be logged in slow log even if indexes are used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that a1ex07 is correct.

However if you want to speed this query up slightly you can change your index on tc from being an index on vtid to being an index on (vtid, userid).  Compound keys like that are much faster if you're joining on both keys, and are almost exactly as fast if you're just joining on the first field.